# Which Microsoft technology to use with AJAX baed SPA applications?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, extjs, sencha-touch

I am about to implement some SPA on ExtJS and Sencha Touch and not shure which technology to choose for beckend:

- ASP.NET
- integration of ExtJS and Touch with ASP.NET MVC
- WebAPI
- WCF

Applications should later use Azure or other Cloud, so that should also be considered.

I know that all is possible but I am not shure what is the best architectual solution.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't matter. We have a bunch of extjs apps that use wcf, other use mvc controllers and yet another group works with web api.

Extjs doesn't comply and happily works in all of these scenarios.

Personally I would go with WebAPI but it is a matter of server-side preferences.